# C counter program always shows zero

Tags: c

I am trying to do a C program that will count the letter of a given string via an input prompt.

However, this code apparently doesn't work and no matter how long the sentence is, letter count always shows 0.
My code looks as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
    //ask for user input
    char *text = get_string("Text: ");

    //letter counter function
    int letter_counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; text[i] ; i++ )
    {
        if (text[i] == isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            letter_counter++;
        }
    }

    //Print the count of LETTERS in the text
    printf("Letter count is: %i\n", letter_counter);

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Sorry if my questions seem stupid, I am still a newbie learning here and know absolutely nothing about C before. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: `if (isalpha(text[i]))`. Because `isalpha` returns 0 or not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement in your code is wrong since you’re comparing the ascii value of every character of the array with the result of the `isAlpha` method which returns 0 if the parameter character is not a letter or a not 0 value if it’s a letter.

So now to fix that you have a few options.
I will recommend these two since your code looks like a mix of both:

You could keep the first part of your `if` statement by checking if is a letter comparing ascii codes:

```
if ((text[i] >= ‘a’ && text[i] <= ‘z’) || (text[i] >= ‘A’ && text[i] <= ‘Z’))
```

Or you could keep the second part of your `if` statement and use the `isAlpha` method:

```
if (isAlpha(text[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`isalpha()` return non zero value which means it is aplhabet. Your condition is wrong .It should be
this:

```
if(isalpha(text[i])!=0)
        letter_counter++;
```

if here `isalpha()` returns zero then it is not alphabet otherwise it if it returns non zero value it is alphabet.

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

Just use: 
if ((text[i] >= ‘a’ && text[i] <= ‘z’) || (text[i] >= ‘A’ && text[i] <= ‘Z’))